# Django rerun operation in migration

Tags: python, django, migration

In my model I made field as unique and did migration for it. Then on production server this migration was crashed, because database has duplicate keys. So I added the following code into my migration:

```
def remove_duplicates(apps, schema_editor):
    Dir = apps.get_model('myapp.projects.models', 'Dir')

    for row in Dir.objects.all():
        if Dir.objects.filter(dir_url=row.dir_url).count() > 1:
            row.delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('projects', '0021_auto_20180412_1215'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_duplicates),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='dir',
            name='dir_url',
            field=models.TextField(unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

But how to test is this code working on my local machine ? When I run `manage.py migrate` again, my function was not been executed and I received message:

> Running migrations:   No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can roll back the migration locally, and then re-apply it.

The previous migration that this one depends on is `0021_auto_20180412_1215`, so you can roll back to that state with:

```
manage.py migrate 0021
```

When you then run `manage.py migrate` again it will apply this new migration afresh.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate):

> `migrate` `<app_label>` `<migrationname>`: Brings the database schema to a state where the named migration is applied, but no later migrations in the same app are applied. This may involve unapplying migrations if you have previously migrated past the named migration.